# How to access stdClass Object array in codeigniter

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I have following `print_r ($rolePermissions);` array result and wondering how can i access only `permID`dynamically.

```
 Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [roleID] => 1 [permID] => 1 ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [roleID] => 1 [permID] => 2 ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [roleID] => 1 [permID] => 3 ) [3] => stdClass Object ( [roleID] => 1 [permID] => 4 ) [4] => stdClass Object ( [roleID] => 1 [permID] => 5 ) [5] => stdClass Object ( [roleID] => 1 [permID] => 6 ) [6] => stdClass Object ( [roleID] => 1 [permID] => 7 ) [7] => stdClass Object ( [roleID] => 1 [permID] => 8 ) [8] => stdClass Object ( [roleID] => 1 [permID] => 9 ) [9] => stdClass Object ( [roleID] => 1 [permID] => 10 ) [10] => stdClass Object ( [roleID] => 1 [permID] => 11 ) [11] => stdClass Object ( [roleID] => 1 [permID] => 12 ) [12] => stdClass Object ( [roleID] => 1 [permID] => 13 ) [13] => stdClass Object ( [roleID] => 1 [permID] => 14 ) [14] => stdClass Object ( [roleID] => 1 [permID] => 15 ) [15] => stdClass Object ( [roleID] => 1 [permID] => 16 ) [16] => stdClass Object ( [roleID] => 1 [permID] => 17 ) [17] => stdClass Object ( [roleID] => 1 [permID] => 18 ) [18] => stdClass Object ( [roleID] => 1 [permID] => 19 ) [19] => stdClass Object ( [roleID] => 1 [permID] => 20 ) [20] => stdClass Object ( [roleID] => 1 [permID] => 21 ) [21] => stdClass Object ( [roleID] => 1 [permID] => 22 ) [22] => stdClass Object ( [roleID] => 1 [permID] => 23 ) [23] => stdClass Object ( [roleID] => 1 [permID] => 24 ) ) [1] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [roleID] => 2 [permID] => 2 ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [roleID] => 2 [permID] => 3 ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [roleID] => 2 [permID] => 4 ) ) [2] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [roleID] => 3 [permID] => 4 ) ) [3] => Array ( ) )
```

I am accessing with following code:

```
$rolePermission[0]->permID
```

But i am unable to get all the records because results can be varied each time and index 0 is not feasible way to do this. It displays some records and pop up errors in others.

```
Error messages:
Undefined offset: 0
Message: Trying to get property of non-object
```

any help ?

Comment: Have provided with a solution for the request that you have asked the question. Have a try and share thoughts.

Answer (score 1):

Either loop over the array:

```
$ids = array();
foreach($rolePermission as $permissionObject){
    $ids[] = $permissionObject->permID;
}
```

Or check that the key exists before accessing it:

```
if(isset($rolePermission[0])) {
    $id = $rolePermission[0]->permID;
}
```

Comment: Specifically you may want to take a look at is_a also: http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-a.php, you can check to see if the object is a stdClass too

Comment: I would suggest an `instanceof` statement rather than an `is_a` statement. Eg: `$rolePermission[0] instanceof stdClass`

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** When you use the `print_r()` it will output the array with `stdClass Object` in CI when you are pulling out a value from the Database.

There is a solution to display the array without using the `stdClass Object` while iterating.

**Example:** Consider `$final` consider the array and while using `print_r()` it displayed the  `stdClass Object`.

- You have to use the loop as follows so that it avoids the `stdClass Object` while printing it.

**Code:**

This code you can use it for the values to retrieve from the DB using the Controller and Model.

> If single row of the output is retrieved from the DB

```
<?php
foreach($final->result() as $single)
{
   //You can print the variable values over here as follows (E.g) echo $single->id    
}
?>
```

> If Multiple row of the output is retrieved from the DB

```
<?php
$row=array();
foreach($final->result() as $single)
{
   //You can store it as an array here if you are going on with multiple loops
   $row[] = $single; 
}
print_r($row); // here you can save it as an another array
?>
```

### How should the model Code look like if you are using `->result()` in the foreach to get the values

Here is the sample that your model should look like if you are using the above methods for the retrieving of the output.

**employee_model.php**

```
<?php
class Employee_model extends CI_Model{
function __construct() {
parent::__construct();
}

public function getEmployees()
{
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('employee');
    $this->db->where('delete_status','0');
    $this->db->where('status','1');
    $this->db->order_by('id','DESC');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query;
}
?>
```

### How to call the model from the controller

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Home extends Layout_Controller {

public function __construct(){
     parent::__construct();
     $this->load->library("pagination");
     $this->load->model('employee_model');
     $this->load->model('ajax_model');         
 }

 public function employee_listing()
 {
     $result['all_employee'] = $this->employee_model->getEmployees(); // getEmployees is the function name in the employee_model
     $this->load->view('frontend/employee_list',$result);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

in Model write this code. last line will get the value of expire column only and will pass to controller. then you can access it form view

```
 function album_expire($user_id ,$album_iid)
{
  $this->db->select('expire');
  $this->db->from('mw_album');
  $this->db->where('user_id', $user_id); 
  $this->db->where('id', $album_iid); 
  return $this->db->get()->row()->expire;
}
```

in controller pass value to view

```
$data['album_expire'] = $this->albums_model->album_expire($user_id ,$album_iid);
```

in view access it like this

```
<?php echo $album_expire; ?>
```